# Set form action dynamically depending on the field filled in by user

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a few different options that all map to different actions, but I only want one submit button.  I cannot for the life of me get this to work.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
function clicked() {
    document.getElementById('id').action = "/query";
    document.getElementById('filename').action = "/fname";
    document.getElementById('dep').action = "/dependency";
    return true;
    }
</script>
<div id="header">
    <h1>TestPy</h1>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="query-menu" id="nav">
        <form name="query_form" id="query" onsubmit="clicked()" method=post>
            <fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
                <legend>Query</legend>
                    <table style="width:25%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Plugin ID:</td>
                        <td><input type=text name=script_id id="id" placeholder="19506"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Filename Search:</td>
                        <td><input type=text name=filename id="fname" placeholder="test.file"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dependency:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=dep id="dep" placeholder="dependency"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2"><td><input type=submit value=Query class="btn"></td></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="section">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is have those three form fields each map back to a separate url, however I cannot get this to work.  If I take the javascript out and hard code the URL, it works fine.  HTML/JavaScript are not my strong language at all so I appreciate any feed back you can provide.  Thanks!

Comment: So how do you decide which action to call?

Comment: how can you do without javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the OnBlur method that triggers whenever a user leaves the input field.

```
<td><input type=text name=filename id="fname" onblur="myFunctionY()" placeholder="test.file"></td>

<td><input type=text name=dep id="dep" onblur="myFunctionY(this)" placeholder="dependency"></td>

<td><input type=text name=script_id id="id" onblur="myFunctionY(this)" placeholder="19506"></td>
```

In Javascript:

```
function myFunctionY(vari) {
console.log(vari.id);
if(vari.id=="fname")
{
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
var link='http://www.google.com?q='+x.value;
console.log("This is the URL "+link);
document.query_form.setAttribute("action",link);
}
if(vari.id=="id")
{
var x = document.getElementById("id");
var link='http://www.google.com?q='+x.value;
console.log("This is the URL "+link);
document.query_form.setAttribute("action",link);
}
if(vari.id=="dep")
{
var x = document.getElementById("dep");
var link='http://www.google.com?q='+x.value;
console.log("This is the URL "+link);
document.query_form.setAttribute("action",link);
}
}
```

You can have 3 functions/ as per your requirement.Upon submitting, it goes to the new action link.

Comment: So this actually worked pretty well for me, except for one little problem and I was wondering if you had an idea.  I'd like each id to go to a different link.  I tried to use an if/elif statement, but the JS code always uses the if statement.  Is there a way to only use the first if statement if the id is empty?  I'm going to keep playing with it and see what I come up with.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChadD, I did figure out a way to ensure it returns different links.I've edited the answer cause it was too long to insert here.Hope it helps, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I'd do something like this:

```
$('#query').submit(function (e) {
    // prevent the default action of form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // create a variable using the 3 field values
    $form_action = '/'+$('#id').val()+'/'+$('#fname').val()+'/'+$('#dep').val();

    // set the form action attribute to the variable value
    $(this).attr('action') = $form_action;

    // submit the form as normal now that the action is changed
    $(this).submit();
});
```